# Pass full file path to php even if directory doesn't exist

Tags: .htaccess

I have got this htaccess in dir1:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ missingFileHandler.php?location=%{REQUEST_FILENAME} [L]
```

When I visit:

```
http://example.com/dir1/dir2/dir3/file.txt
```

The value of $_GET['location'] is fine:

```
/path-to-www/dir1/dir2/dir3/file.txt
```

However if some the the dir1, dir2 or dir3 doesn't exist, I don't get the full path, e.g. when visiting:

```
http://example.com/dir1/missingdir2/dir3/file.txt
```

The value of $_GET['location'] is missing the rest:

```
/path-to-www/dir1/missingdir2
```

How can I get the full path in both cases?

`Note:`

It doesn't need to be the full server path or full url.
All I am really interested in is this part: `dir1/dir2/dir3/file.txt`

Comment: Can't you use `%{REQUEST_URI}` instead of `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ missingFileHandler.php?location=$1 [L]
```

Comment: That works fine, thank you. Can you please explain the `^(.+)$` bit? I did try `$1` before, but I was getting an empty string in $_GET['location'].

Comment: ^(.+)$ (Regex capture group) matches any request that is not a real file and dir and saves the captured value as $1.